# Why the rituals pertaining to birth, upanayan, marriage and death are different among the Hindus?

Tags: rituals

Why the rituals pertaining to birth, upanayan, marriage and death are different among the Hindus? Is there a different sanction when it comes to rituals? Even among the Brahmins there is NO uniform code of conduct. Is it more influenced by the local culture rather than the scriptures? How this is possible?

And is there a common code of conduct, which has been flouted from ages so much so that there is no standard to go back to.

Comment: it is based on scripture only. and scripture itself is different for different locations based on Rishi, Veda, Parampara. Think of it as one Major scripture with sub-headings for each sect.